# Unslider Carousel not working properly. Li Data Slide numbers appearing below slider

Tags: jquery, unslider

The unslider carousel keeps showing number 1234 for the slides. when i inspect element is shows that is the li data slide numbers, but they arent in my html as seen below. not sure how to get rid of them..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>



        <link href="css/unslider.css" rel="stylesheet">

         <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/icon.ico"/>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <title>Axel McHugh</title>

           <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/1.ico"/>








        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


        <link href="css/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet">





    </head>

    <body>

  <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-left:25px">






     <div class="row">



            <div class="col-md-2">

                   <a href="index.html"> <h2 class="title">Axel McHugh</h2></a>

                 <ul>
            <li class="toplistindex"><p3>Projects</h2></li>
            <li class="normlist"><a href="iadt.html"><p4 class="title">IADT Gradshow<p4></a></li>
            <li class="normlist"><a href="welcome.html"><p4 class="title">Welcome<p4></a></li>
                 <li class="normlist"><a href="iapi.html"><p4 class="title">IAPI Census<p4></a></li>
                      <li class="normlist"><a href="spark.html"><p4 class="title">Spark<p4></a></li>
                           <li class="normlist"><a href="dcu.html"><p4 class="title">Dublin City University<p4></a></li>
                               <li class="normlist"><a href="kuuki.html"><p4 class="title">KUUKI<p4></a></li>

                       <li class="bottomlist"><a href="about.html"><p4 class="title">About / Contact<p4></a></li>




                    </ul> 
                    </div>








                   <div class="col-md-8" style="
    padding-left: 0px;
">                
   <div class="banner">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="img/grad.jpg" class="img-responsive"</li>
            <li><img src="img/grad.jpg" class="img-responsive"</li>
                <li><img src="img/grad.jpg" class="img-responsive"</li>
        <li><img src="img/grad.jpg" class="img-responsive"</li>
    </ul>
</div></div>










                               </div>





              </div>













     <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
     <script src="js/unslider.js"></script>

    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>


       <script>





           $(function() { $('.banner').unslider() })


        </script>

       <script>
           $('.banner').unslider({
               infinite: true,
               autoplay: true,
               delay: 3000,
               speed: 1000,
               keys: true,

});

        </script>      

                          <script>

                          if (index == $("#hp-banner-right li").length)
{
  var data = slidey.data('unslider');
  data.speed = 0;
  data.move(0, function () {})
  data.speed = 500;
  $('#hp-banner-right li').removeClass ('active').eq (0).addClass ('active');
}</script>



    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you mean that instead of the dots appearing under the photos, that numbers are?

Comment: Nvm, I see the issue. You didn't close your image tags. And if there is nothing inside the list element, it generates a label for you based on the slide number.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Fix these first: `<li><img src="img/grad.jpg" class="img-responsive"</li>`

Answer (score 0):

fixed img tags, still these labels appear. seems to be something to do with bootstrap.min?

Comment: There's something in bootstrap min i believe that is taking however many slides i have, say 4, and bottom left of the slider outside of the slider it has what seems to be an ordered list saying 1 2 3 4